# ArcPy Data Driven Pages AttributeError: PageLayoutObject: Error in exporting pages

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, export, pdf, data-driven-pages

I am trying to create an atlas with embedded title page and extra reports pages. Seems that I need to use Python scripts for this. I am not programmer and never worked with python. I found necessary script but then faced with a problem to make an export of pages from mxd

Please see my script:

```
        import arcpy, os

# Create an output location variable
outDir = "K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/Final"  

# Create a new, empty pdf document in the specified output location folder
finalpdf_filename = outDir + "/Test_Atlas_Final.pdf"
if os.path.exists(finalpdf_filename):
  os.remove(finalpdf_filename)
finalPdf = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(finalpdf_filename) 

# Add the title page to the pdf
finalPdf.appendPages("K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/TitlePage.pdf")

# Add the overview map to the pdf
finalPdf.appendPages("K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/IndexMap.pdf")

# Export the Data Driven Pages to a temporary pdf and then add it to the
# final pdf. Alternately, if your Data Driven Pages have already been
# exported, simply append that document to the final pdf.
#
mxdPath = "K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/AOR_General_v2_Atlas_Test1_1.mxd"
tempMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
tempDDP = tempMap.dataDrivenPages
temp_filename = "K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/tempDDP.pdf"
if os.path.exists(temp_filename):
  os.remove(temp_filename)
tempDDP.exportToPDF(temp_filename, "ALL")
finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename)

# Insert the pdf pages containing the reports and graphs into the final pdf
#
finalPdf.insertPages("K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/Report_pg4.pdf", 4)
# Update the properties of the final pdf
finalPdf.updateDocProperties(pdf_open_view="USE_THUMBS",
pdf_layout="SINGLE_PAGE")

# Save your result
finalPdf.saveAndClose()

# Delete variables
del finalPdf
```

Error I keep getting

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\_mapping.py", line 447, in exportToPDF
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.exportToPDF(*gp_fixargs((out_pdf, page_range_type, page_range_string, multiple_files, resolution, image_quality, colorspace, compress_vectors, image_compression, picture_symbol, convert_markers, embed_fonts, layers_attributes, georef_info, jpeg_compression_quality, show_selection_symbology), True)))
AttributeError: PageLayoutObject: Error in exporting pages
```

It works well till this step **# Add the overview map to the pdf**
It adding overview map perfectly and error occurs during proceeding of the next step.

Comment: Based on the error the problem is actually occurring at tempDDP.exportToPDF(temp_filename, "ALL") ; I have had problems here before, one fix was to remove .pdf from the output name as exportToPDF adds the file extension. So I would change temp_filename = "K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/tempDDP.pdf"    -to-    temp_filename = "K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/tempDDP"         then finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename + ".pdf")

Comment: @Clubdebambos That would be worth adding as an answer, which would allow you to format the code better also.  I recommend including all of that specific code block for clarity ( from `mxdPath` to `finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename)` )

Comment: @Midavalo I just ran the code provided by just changing paths and pdfs that I have and everything worked fine. So I don't think my suggestion is the root cause.

Comment: @Clubdebambos I did also, but if you've had problems there in the past, it is a potential fix.  Might be ArcMap version specific

Comment: @Dia What ArcGIS version are you running?

Comment: I use DDP and Python quite a lot and the only other issues I had that might help 1) if jpegs or images are placed/embedded into the map (not the layout) using Python to export DDP outside of a toolbox fails. 2) DDP is not set up correctly, make sure that Name Field, Sort Field and Page Name are correct and do not use OBJECTID for any of these.

Answer (score 1):

Change the temp_filename and finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename + ".pdf")

```
import arcpy, os

# Create an output location variable
outDir = "K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/Final"  

# Create a new, empty pdf document in the specified output location folder
finalpdf_filename = outDir + "/Test_Atlas_Final.pdf"
if os.path.exists(finalpdf_filename):
  os.remove(finalpdf_filename)
finalPdf = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(finalpdf_filename) 

# Add the title page to the pdf
finalPdf.appendPages("K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/TitlePage.pdf")

# Add the overview map to the pdf
finalPdf.appendPages("K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/IndexMap.pdf")

# Export the Data Driven Pages to a temporary pdf and then add it to the
# final pdf. Alternately, if your Data Driven Pages have already been
# exported, simply append that document to the final pdf.
#
mxdPath = "K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/AOR_General_v2_Atlas_Test1_1.mxd"
tempMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
tempDDP = tempMap.dataDrivenPages
temp_filename = "K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/tempDDP"
if os.path.exists(temp_filename):
  os.remove(temp_filename)
tempDDP.exportToPDF(temp_filename, "ALL")
finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename + ".pdf")

# Insert the pdf pages containing the reports and graphs into the final pdf
#
finalPdf.insertPages("K:/IM/02_GIS/01_Projects/Report_pg4.pdf", 4)
# Update the properties of the final pdf
finalPdf.updateDocProperties(pdf_open_view="USE_THUMBS",
pdf_layout="SINGLE_PAGE")

# Save your result
finalPdf.saveAndClose()

# Delete variables
del finalPdf
```